# Cannot assign "'1'": "Cliente.tipo_cliente" must be a "TipoCliente" instance

Tags: django, django-models

Estoy tratando de guardar el formulario que hize en django el cual tiene una foreignkey del modelo cliente al modelo tipo de cliente pero al momento de guardar sale este error.

> Cannot assign "'1'": "Cliente.tipo_cliente" must be a "TipoCliente"
>   instance

**modelos.py**

```
class TipoCliente(models.Model):
    codigo = models.IntegerField()
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Cliente(models.Model):
    tipo_cliente = models.ForeignKey('TipoCliente')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

**views.py**

```
tipo_cliente = TipoCliente.objects.all()

cliente = Cliente()
cliente.tipo_cliente = request.POST['tipo_cliente']
cliente.nombre = request.POST['nombre']
cliente.save()
```

**error**

> ValueError at /generales/clientes
>
> Cannot assign "'1'": "Cliente.tipo_cliente" must be a "TipoCliente" instance.
>
> Django Version:   1.10.2
>
> Exception Type:   ValueError
>
> Exception Value:
>
> Cannot assign "'1'": "Cliente.tipo_cliente" must be a "TipoCliente" instance.

**Utilizando el form de Django funciona perfectamente pero me toca hacerlo sin usar el form de Django.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `error` es claro , `tipo_cliente` debe recibir un Objeto de tipo `TipoCliente` pero en su lugar usted asigna una cadena que recibe por `POST`
Filtrar el `TipoCliente` por el tipo que recibe por `POST` para luego asignar al atributo `tipo_cliente` del Modelo `Cliente`

```
cliente = Cliente()
cliente.tipo_cliente = TipoCliente.objects.get(codigo = request.POST['tipo_cliente'])
cliente.nombre = request.POST['nombre']
cliente.save()
```

Comment: Usando `cliente.tipo_cliente_id = request.POST['tipo_cliente']` se ahorra una consulta a la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que así te va a funcionar:

```
tipo = TipoCliente.objects.get(pk = request.POST['tipo_cliente']) # Obtengo el objeto de TipoCliente
cliente = Cliente()
cliente.tipo_cliente = tipo
cliente.nombre = request.POST['nombre']
cliente.save()
```

Lo que está pasando es que estas asignando un integer a un campo que es una clave foránea, como en Django se realiza un mapeo de la base de datos esa foránea se convierte en un objeto del tipo TipoCliente. Ahí es cuando surge la incompatibilidad